# Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I can't get my head around why I'm getting this error. Does anyone know what is wrong with the code? The code worked when there was only the "class image" and the error started appearing after I added back "function App()".

App.js =>

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import UploadImages from "./components/image-upload.component";
import styled from "styled-components";

function App() {
  const [url, setURL] = useState("");

  const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

  const [urls, setURLs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const urls = [
      250940,
      20622,
      436625,
      436444,
      436509,
      359245,
      459090,
      333933,
      333916,
      466350,
      44831,
      383010,
      202660,
      406317,
      337349,
      503448,
      12617,
      248662,
      435805,
      438545
    ].map(
      (itemId) =>
        `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${itemId}`
    );
  
    Promise.all(
      urls.map((currUrl) =>
        fetch(currUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => data.primaryImage)
          .catch((error) => console.log("There was a problem!", error))
      )
    ).then((fetchedUrls) => setURLs(fetchedUrls));
  }, []);

  class image extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.onClickNext = this.onClickNext.bind(this)
      this.onClickPrevious = this.onClickPrevious.bind(this)

      const img0 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/gr/original/DP146615.jpg'
      const img1 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/original/DP253076.jpg'
      const img2 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ep/original/DP146499.jpg'
      const img3 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ep/original/EP1455.jpg'
      const img4 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ep/original/DT2580.jpg'
      const img5 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/dp/original/DP821059.jpg'
      const img6 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/rl/original/DP295708.jpg'
      const img7 = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/dp/original/DP805154.jpg'

      this.state = {
        index: 0,
        imgList: [img0 ,img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7]
      }
    }

      // imgList: [urls[1], urls[2], urls[3], urls[4], urls[5], urls[6], urls[7], urls[8], urls[9], urls[10], urls[11], urls[12], urls[13], urls[14], urls[15], urls[16], urls[17], urls[18], urls[19], urls[20]]

    onClickNext() {
      if (this.state.index + 1 === this.state.imgList.length) {
        this.setState({
          index: 0
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          index: this.state.index + 1
        })
      }
    }

    onClickPrevious() {
        if (this.state.index - 1 === -1) {
        this.setState({
          index: this.state.imgList.length -1
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          index: this.state.index -1
        })
      }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="productsContainer">
          <div className="images">
            <div className="images__item">
              <img className="photo" src={this.state.imgList[this.state.index]}/>
            </div>
            <div className="images__item">
              <img className="photo" src={this.state.imgList[this.state.index + 1]}/>
            </div>
            <div className="images__item">
              <img className="photo" src={this.state.imgList[this.state.index + 2]}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onClickPrevious}>Previous</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClickNext}>Next</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Full error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: `App` doesn't return anything. Why is the class inside `App`?

Comment: you have class component inside function component ?

Comment: besides you are mixing hooks with class component. you should pick one, not use both together.

Comment: Should I then instead solely use the class component?

Comment: Problem is that useEffect can not be called in a class component, it must be called in a react function or custom hook function. Or is there a way to implement it? Same goes for useState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering anything in your `<App>`. You need to return your component. I renamed it from `<Image>` to `<ImageCarousel>`.

I also cleaned-up the modular math.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const images = [
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/gr/original/DP146615.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/original/DP253076.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ep/original/DP146499.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ep/original/EP1455.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ep/original/DT2580.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/dp/original/DP821059.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/rl/original/DP295708.jpg',
  'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/dp/original/DP805154.jpg'
];

class ImageCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const { images } = props;

    this.onClickNext = this.onClickNext.bind(this)
    this.onClickPrevious = this.onClickPrevious.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      imgList: images
    }
  }

  onClickNext() {
    this.rotateIndex(1);
  }

  onClickPrevious() {
    this.rotateIndex(-1);
  }
  
  rotateIndex(direction) {
    const { index, imgList: { length }} = this.state;
    this.setState({
      index: this.calculateIndexOffset(index, direction, length)
    });
  }
  
  calculateIndexOffset(start, offset, size) {
    return (start + size + offset)  % size;
  }
  
  indexOffset(offset = 0) {
    const { index, imgList: { length }} = this.state;
    return this.calculateIndexOffset(index, offset, length);
  }
  
  imageOffset(offset = 0) {
    return this.state.imgList[this.indexOffset(offset)];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="imageCarousel">
        <div className="productsContainer">
          <div className="images">
            <div className="images__item">
              <img className="photo" src={this.imageOffset()}/>
            </div>
            <div className="images__item">
              <img className="photo" src={this.imageOffset(1)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="images__item">
              <img className="photo" src={this.imageOffset(2)}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
          <button onClick={this.onClickPrevious}>Previous</button>
          <button onClick={this.onClickNext}>Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [url, setURL] = useState("");
  const [urls, setURLs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const urls = [
      250940,
      20622,
      436625,
      436444,
      436509,
      359245,
      459090,
      333933,
      333916,
      466350,
      44831,
      383010,
      202660,
      406317,
      337349,
      503448,
      12617,
      248662,
      435805,
      438545
    ].map(
      (itemId) =>
        `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${itemId}`
    );
  
    Promise.all(
      urls.map((currUrl) =>
        fetch(currUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => data.primaryImage)
          .catch((error) => console.log("There was a problem!", error))
      )
    ).then((fetchedUrls) => setURLs(fetchedUrls));
  }, []);
  
  return <ImageCarousel images={images} />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.imageCarousel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
}

.imageCarousel .productsContainer .images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.images__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.images__item .photo {
  max-height: 160px;
  flex: 1;
}

.imageCarousel .buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```